# Apache Web Server Application Deployment

Tags: apache, web, server, webserver

We are in active process of developing web application under [Apache Web Server](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi).

What is web application structure, that should be deployed on  [Apache Web Server](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi)? Is there documentation available?

Answer (score 2):

After installing Apache Web server 
you need

1) Mysql to access database and store your data

2) PHP to run scripts for retrieving data from database to display it and to save data to the database.

For windows users :

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html#installComponentsSeparately

For Linux users:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04